# How to restrict (Cloudflared or any ) Docker container any access to host network except internet gateway

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, cloudflare, check-mk

I am running a Checkmk container alongside a Cloudflared Tunnel container in a docker-compose on my WSL.
As of now the tunnel is configured to point from my subdomain to the Checkmk container and makes it available to the outside world.

Only problem is that the Cloudflared container itself not only has access to the Checkmk container but also the whole network of my host machine.

This is technically not a big problem because I can set the access of the tunnel to the Checkmk container only, but I don't really want anyone who gained access to my Tunnel settings to just type in the host name of my smarthome server or my router and gaining access to the gui that way, because as of right now that is possible.

Can someone please tell me how I set the Cloudflared container that it can only see the Checkmk container and the IP of my gateway as if nothing else is there?
Can i set a Docker network up that is isolated to the host but not to the hosts internet gateway?
Or do i need to configure the firewall of the host system in a special way?

Thank you,
Bims

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  cmk:
    image: checkmk/check-mk-raw:2.0.0-latest
    tmpfs:
     - /opt/omd/sites/cmk/tmp:uid=1000,gid=1000
    ulimits:
      nofile: 1024
    container_name: checkmk
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - '/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro'
      - './omd-sites:/omd/sites'
    ports:
      - '8095:5000'
      - '6557:6557'
  
  cloudflared:
    image: "cloudflare/cloudflared:latest"
    command: tunnel run
    environment:
      - TUNNEL_TOKEN= [redacted]
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - cmk
```